# How would I create a regex that can match any of several words?

Tags: java, regex, syntax

Like I want it to trigger on Word1, Word2, or Word3.

For example:
`(Cleave|Flame|Punch|Fire Aspect|Knockback)`

But that just matches individual letters.

Comment: what fails exaclly? is the word standalone or is it part of a sentence?
what is the code you have written and fails?

Comment: That can't match letters, you have a *grouping* construct that matches alternative *sequences of letters/spaces*.

Comment: You can do separate method :). Like so:

public bool checkWord(String word)
{
    if( word.equals("clave" || "word1" /*etc...*/ )
        return false;
    return true;
}